# Enable registration only for selective product WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

I am using WooCommerce membership for one product and the rest of the WooCommerce products are generic products.

But I want that the visitors should be able to register for WooCommerce membership but not for other products. For other products, I would like to use guest checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a [solution](https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/5fadb94dd9eff11ab512) on GitHub that you can use.

```
// Code goes in theme functions.php or a custom plugin
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_enable_guest_checkout', 'conditional_guest_checkout_based_on_product' );
function conditional_guest_checkout_based_on_product( $value ) {
  $restrict_ids = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // Replace with product ids which cannot use guest checkout

  if ( WC()->cart ) {
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    foreach ( $cart as $item ) {
      if ( in_array( $item['product_id'], $restrict_ids ) ) {
        $value = "no";
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $value;
}
```