# How can I specify that if a product needs to be registered, email will be required؟

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce membership for one product and the rest of the WooCommerce products are generic products.

I use this code for this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49062030/15301902)

I use this code to customize the email on the WooCommerce checkout page. How can I specify that if a product needs to be registered, email will be required?

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'ts_unrequire_wc_email_field');
function ts_unrequire_wc_email_field( $fields ) {
$fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;
return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'woo_email_validation', 20);

function woo_email_validation($fields){

    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['required'] = true; // true => required | false => not required

    return $fields;

}
```

Comment: This code does not work. This code requires email for all products.

Answer (score 0):

I want the email to be required when one of the products needs to be registered using this code:

```
// Code goes in theme functions.php or a custom plugin
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_enable_guest_checkout', 'conditional_guest_checkout_based_on_product' );
function conditional_guest_checkout_based_on_product( $value ) {
  $restrict_ids = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // Replace with product ids which cannot use guest checkout

  if ( WC()->cart ) {
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    foreach ( $cart as $item ) {
      if ( in_array( $item['product_id'], $restrict_ids ) ) {
        $value = "no";
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return $value;
}
```

And in other cases where the product can be purchased as a guest, email is not required.